# emails sent three times asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, iis, web-config

I am working on a e-commerce website and there is an issue which we are trying to solve.
After customer completed order she is receiving three emails (all of them same) instead of one. 
The website is running on three servers and we think that's the problem because using only one server brings one email delivered to the customer.
I would like to know what we should do so the user will receive only one email instead of three and we will still run the website on three servers.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Could this be a simple concurrency issue that a `lock(object){}` around the email.Send (in conjunction with a flag) will do? Are you using `System.Net.Mail`?

Comment: @James  Thanks for your reply. Email is first queued in db table and then is sent via DB.

Comment: please can you copy/paste the send email code for us

Comment: If you are load-balancing your site with three servers they will still have to communicate to avoid situations like that in the question. It sounds more like a design problem than a code problem.

Comment: Are you load balancing the servers?  Can you reproduce this problem in a test lab?  Is it only one customer or all customers?

Comment: Who queues the emails, and how are the emails sent (consumed from the queue)? It seems like it could be one of two things: 3 emails are being queued, or there's three consumers on the same queue without locking.

Comment: Yes, load balancing. For example, customer places an order and then it receives three confirmation emails. When order is shipped and email is sent to customer then he is receiving another three emails for shipping confirmation. @DavidPerlman how do you think we can change the design if this is design problem. All Customers. One email is queued and three times is sent.

Comment: Are you using only one database? If so lock the row when reading, set a flag when the send is completed, the release the row.

Comment: Where is the code that sends the email initiated from? Is it a windows service that runs and checks the db? What event initiates the email sending code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot count on locking hints in the database for this.  A hint is just a hint; there's no guarantee that the locking will happen as you expect (assuming this is SQL Server).  In general, a relational database is just that, a database.  A table is not a queuing mechanism and you will always have problems if you try to use it that way.

Nonetheless, in order to implement a different solution, we have to determine if a single record is being added to the "queue" or if three records are being added.  If it is the first, and only a single record is added but three emails are sent out then the solution is simple.  Instead of using a database table as your queue, use Microsoft Message Queues (MSMQ) instead.  They are part of Windows Server and have been since at least 2003, maybe even all the way back to 2000.  They will provide you with an actual queue specifically designed for what you're trying to accomplish.

If there are three actual records being added to the "queue" table in the database that means there is a code problem.  Even with three Web servers in the load balancer, the fact remains that a single order submission only happens on one of those servers.  The business logic that places the email notification in the queue could not come from more than one server because the request only originates from one server.

I would check the table first and determine if there are multiple records being added.  If not, change the implementation to use MSMQ.  If so, check your code to see why more than one record is being added in the request.

Comment: @Christoper Thanks for your detailed explanation. I checked the table and only one record is being added. How can I change the implementation to use MSMQ, since now all the data is going to the table 1st. Do I need to make complete code changes to switch to MSMQ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, incorporating MSMQ would be a complete code change.  Your Web application will place a message on the queue using methods and classes native to the .NET Framework.  Then you'll need to create a Windows service that monitors the queue.  When a message arrives at the head of the queue the service will automatically "process" it.  Depending on the amount of messages on the queue you could have the main thread hand it off to multiple work threads or just deal with the one single thread.  Either way, it will resolve your problems and will actually perform and scale very well.